# Can we allow user to create data with only specific fields using firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When submitting data, I want to ensure that my client cannot persist random fields.

Meanwhile, I want to keep my app the simplest as possible and I am trying to do it using only firestore rules and/or indexes (i.e. not using some server side express). Is it possible?

I know how to check the existence and the type of a field :

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /example/{exampleId} {
      allow create: if "fieldOK" in request.resource.data &&
        request.resource.data.fieldOK is string
    }
  }
}
```

But I do not know how to block the creation of a random field such as "fieldBS" when you cannot do a loop in your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ensure that an object has only a certain range of keys using `hasAll` or `hasOnly`.

```
request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['admin']);
request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['admin']);
```

You can use this at arbitrary levels of nesting on `Map` (key/value pair) style data.

The [Firebase Rules Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/) is a great resource for questions like this.

After checking only the supported range of keys are present, it's still important to sanity check each individual field thereafter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Would be great to have it mentioned in the documentation as the reference is not so user friendly and even the full examples (such as the rating app) does not use this function.

Comment: No I agree, it's really, really tough going. There was a great website which contained a cheat sheet for this kind of thing, but unfortunately I can't find it. If I stumble across it again I will notify you here.